# Kubeflow pipeline error: failed to save outputs: No such container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, pipeline, kubeflow

While trying to setup my own kubeflow pipeline I ran into a problem when one step is finished and the outputs should be saved. After finishing the step kubeflow always throws an error with the message `This step is in Error state with this message: failed to save outputs: Error response from daemon: No such container: <container-id>`

First I thought I would have made a mistake with my pipeline, but it's the same with the preexisting examples pipeline, e.g. for "[Sample] Basic - Conditional execution" I get this message after the first step (flip-coin) is finished.

The main container shows output:

```
heads
```

So it seems to have run successfully.

The wait container shows following output:

```
time="2019-06-07T11:41:35Z" level=info msg="Creating a docker executor"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:35Z" level=info msg="Executor (version: v2.2.0, build_date: 2018-08-30T08:52:54Z) initialized with template:\narchiveLocation:\n  s3:\n    accessKeySecret:\n      key: accesskey\n      name: mlpipeline-minio-artifact\n    bucket: mlpipeline\n    endpoint: minio-service.kubeflow:9000\n    insecure: true\n    key: artifacts/conditional-execution-pipeline-vmdhx/conditional-execution-pipeline-vmdhx-2104306666\n    secretKeySecret:\n      key: secretkey\n      name: mlpipeline-minio-artifact\ncontainer:\n  args:\n  - python -c \"import random; result = 'heads' if random.randint(0,1) == 0 else 'tails';\n    print(result)\" | tee /tmp/output\n  command:\n  - sh\n  - -c\n  image: python:alpine3.6\n  name: \"\"\n  resources: {}\ninputs: {}\nmetadata: {}\nname: flip-coin\noutputs:\n  artifacts:\n  - name: mlpipeline-ui-metadata\n    path: /mlpipeline-ui-metadata.json\n  - name: mlpipeline-metrics\n    path: /mlpipeline-metrics.json\n  parameters:\n  - name: flip-coin-output\n    valueFrom:\n      path: /tmp/output\n"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:35Z" level=info msg="Waiting on main container"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:36Z" level=info msg="main container started with container ID: 7e3064415736db584cac5598a2b2a28728e11c03014ac67a05d008ad8119b13c"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:36Z" level=info msg="Starting annotations monitor"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:36Z" level=info msg="docker wait 7e3064415736db584cac5598a2b2a28728e11c03014ac67a05d008ad8119b13c"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:36Z" level=info msg="Starting deadline monitor"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=error msg="`docker wait 7e3064415736db584cac5598a2b2a28728e11c03014ac67a05d008ad8119b13c` failed: Error response from daemon: No such container: 7e3064415736db584cac5598a2b2a28728e11c03014ac67a05d008ad8119b13c\n"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Main container completed"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="No sidecars"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Saving output artifacts"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Annotations monitor stopped"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Saving artifact: mlpipeline-ui-metadata"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Archiving 7e3064415736db584cac5598a2b2a28728e11c03014ac67a05d008ad8119b13c:/mlpipeline-ui-metadata.json to /argo/outputs/artifacts/mlpipeline-ui-metadata.tgz"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="sh -c docker cp -a 7e3064415736db584cac5598a2b2a28728e11c03014ac67a05d008ad8119b13c:/mlpipeline-ui-metadata.json - | gzip > /argo/outputs/artifacts/mlpipeline-ui-metadata.tgz"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Archiving completed"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Creating minio client minio-service.kubeflow:9000 using static credentials"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Saving from /argo/outputs/artifacts/mlpipeline-ui-metadata.tgz to s3 (endpoint: minio-service.kubeflow:9000, bucket: mlpipeline, key: artifacts/conditional-execution-pipeline-vmdhx/conditional-execution-pipeline-vmdhx-2104306666/mlpipeline-ui-metadata.tgz)"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Successfully saved file: /argo/outputs/artifacts/mlpipeline-ui-metadata.tgz"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Saving artifact: mlpipeline-metrics"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Archiving 7e3064415736db584cac5598a2b2a28728e11c03014ac67a05d008ad8119b13c:/mlpipeline-metrics.json to /argo/outputs/artifacts/mlpipeline-metrics.tgz"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="sh -c docker cp -a 7e3064415736db584cac5598a2b2a28728e11c03014ac67a05d008ad8119b13c:/mlpipeline-metrics.json - | gzip > /argo/outputs/artifacts/mlpipeline-metrics.tgz"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Archiving completed"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Creating minio client minio-service.kubeflow:9000 using static credentials"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Saving from /argo/outputs/artifacts/mlpipeline-metrics.tgz to s3 (endpoint: minio-service.kubeflow:9000, bucket: mlpipeline, key: artifacts/conditional-execution-pipeline-vmdhx/conditional-execution-pipeline-vmdhx-2104306666/mlpipeline-metrics.tgz)"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Successfully saved file: /argo/outputs/artifacts/mlpipeline-metrics.tgz"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Saving output parameters"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Saving path output parameter: flip-coin-output"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="[sh -c docker cp -a 7e3064415736db584cac5598a2b2a28728e11c03014ac67a05d008ad8119b13c:/tmp/output - | tar -ax -O]"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=error msg="`[sh -c docker cp -a 7e3064415736db584cac5598a2b2a28728e11c03014ac67a05d008ad8119b13c:/tmp/output - | tar -ax -O]` stderr:\nError: No such container:path: 7e3064415736db584cac5598a2b2a28728e11c03014ac67a05d008ad8119b13c:/tmp/output\ntar: This does not look like a tar archive\ntar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors\n"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=info msg="Alloc=4338 TotalAlloc=11911 Sys=10598 NumGC=4 Goroutines=11"
time="2019-06-07T11:41:37Z" level=fatal msg="exit status 2\ngithub.com/argoproj/argo/errors.Wrap\n\t/root/go/src/github.com/argoproj/argo/errors/errors.go:87\ngithub.com/argoproj/argo/errors.InternalWrapError\n\t/root/go/src/github.com/argoproj/argo/errors/errors.go:70\ngithub.com/argoproj/argo/workflow/executor/docker.(*DockerExecutor).GetFileContents\n\t/root/go/src/github.com/argoproj/argo/workflow/executor/docker/docker.go:40\ngithub.com/argoproj/argo/workflow/executor.(*WorkflowExecutor).SaveParameters\n\t/root/go/src/github.com/argoproj/argo/workflow/executor/executor.go:343\ngithub.com/argoproj/argo/cmd/argoexec/commands.waitContainer\n\t/root/go/src/github.com/argoproj/argo/cmd/argoexec/commands/wait.go:49\ngithub.com/argoproj/argo/cmd/argoexec/commands.glob..func4\n\t/root/go/src/github.com/argoproj/argo/cmd/argoexec/commands/wait.go:19\ngithub.com/argoproj/argo/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute\n\t/root/go/src/github.com/argoproj/argo/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:766\ngithub.com/argoproj/argo/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC\n\t/root/go/src/github.com/argoproj/argo/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:852\ngithub.com/argoproj/argo/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute\n\t/root/go/src/github.com/argoproj/argo/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:800\nmain.main\n\t/root/go/src/github.com/argoproj/argo/cmd/argoexec/main.go:15\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:198\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361"
```

So it seems that there is a problem with either kubeflow or my docker daemon. The output of `kubectl describe pods` for the created pod is following:

```
Name:               conditional-execution-pipeline-vmdhx-2104306666
Namespace:          kubeflow
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               root-nuc8i5beh/9.233.5.90
Start Time:         Fri, 07 Jun 2019 13:41:29 +0200
Labels:             workflows.argoproj.io/completed=true
                    workflows.argoproj.io/workflow=conditional-execution-pipeline-vmdhx
Annotations:        workflows.argoproj.io/node-message:
                      Error response from daemon: No such container: 7e3064415736db584cac5598a2b2a28728e11c03014ac67a05d008ad8119b13c
                    workflows.argoproj.io/node-name: conditional-execution-pipeline-vmdhx.flip-coin
                    workflows.argoproj.io/template:
                      {"name":"flip-coin","inputs":{},"outputs":{"parameters":[{"name":"flip-coin-output","valueFrom":{"path":"/tmp/output"}}],"artifacts":[{"na...
Status:             Failed
IP:                 10.1.1.30
Controlled By:      Workflow/conditional-execution-pipeline-vmdhx
Containers:
  main:
    Container ID:  containerd://7e3064415736db584cac5598a2b2a28728e11c03014ac67a05d008ad8119b13c
    Image:         python:alpine3.6
    Image ID:      docker.io/library/python@sha256:766a961bf699491995cc29e20958ef11fd63741ff41dcc70ec34355b39d52971
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
    Args:
      python -c "import random; result = 'heads' if random.randint(0,1) == 0 else 'tails'; print(result)" | tee /tmp/output
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 07 Jun 2019 13:41:35 +0200
      Finished:     Fri, 07 Jun 2019 13:41:35 +0200
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from pipeline-runner-token-xh2p7 (ro)
  wait:
    Container ID:  containerd://f0449dc70c0a651c09aeb883edda9ce0ec5e415fa15a5468fe5b360fb06637c2
    Image:         argoproj/argoexec:v2.2.0
    Image ID:      docker.io/argoproj/argoexec@sha256:eea81e0b0d8899a0b7f9815c9c7bd89afa73ab32e5238430de82342b3bb7674a
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      argoexec
    Args:
      wait
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Fri, 07 Jun 2019 13:41:35 +0200
      Finished:     Fri, 07 Jun 2019 13:41:37 +0200
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      ARGO_POD_NAME:  conditional-execution-pipeline-vmdhx-2104306666 (v1:metadata.name)
    Mounts:
      /argo/podmetadata from podmetadata (rw)
      /var/lib/docker from docker-lib (ro)
      /var/run/docker.sock from docker-sock (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from pipeline-runner-token-xh2p7 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  podmetadata:
    Type:  DownwardAPI (a volume populated by information about the pod)
    Items:
      metadata.annotations -> annotations
  docker-lib:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/lib/docker
    HostPathType:  Directory
  docker-sock:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/run/docker.sock
    HostPathType:  Socket
  pipeline-runner-token-xh2p7:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  pipeline-runner-token-xh2p7
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From                     Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----                     -------
  Normal  Scheduled  8m1s   default-scheduler        Successfully assigned kubeflow/conditional-execution-pipeline-vmdhx-2104306666 to root-nuc8i5beh
  Normal  Pulling    8m1s   kubelet, root-nuc8i5beh  Pulling image "python:alpine3.6"
  Normal  Pulled     7m56s  kubelet, root-nuc8i5beh  Successfully pulled image "python:alpine3.6"
  Normal  Created    7m56s  kubelet, root-nuc8i5beh  Created container main
  Normal  Started    7m55s  kubelet, root-nuc8i5beh  Started container main
  Normal  Pulled     7m55s  kubelet, root-nuc8i5beh  Container image "argoproj/argoexec:v2.2.0" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    7m55s  kubelet, root-nuc8i5beh  Created container wait
  Normal  Started    7m55s  kubelet, root-nuc8i5beh  Started container wait
```

So probably there is a problem with the argoexec container image? I see it tries to mount /var/run/docker.sock. When I try to read this file with `cat` I get a "No such device or address" even though I can see the file with `ls /var/run`. When I try to open it with `vi` it mentions that the Permissions were denied, so I cannot see inside of the file. Is this the usual behavior with this file or does it seem like there are any problems with it?

I would really appreciate any help I can get! Thank you guys!

Comment: Sounds like kubeflow instalation issue

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already reinstalled it a few times. The "default" kubeflow toolkit doesnt work at all on my machine, so I only installed the pipelines kit, this worked except for this error. Do you know what could be the problem with my installation?

Comment: I've installed KF into gke cluster without problems following the docs :/ weird is the fact that coinflip works but conditional pipeline does not. Is there any possibility you have more than 110 pods running? That is the limit per node.

Comment: No I dont have more than 110 pods running, should not be more like 15 or so :D
Im installing it locally on a Microk8s cluster, not on GKE. Ive heard of a few problems with how microk8s and kubeflow work together, so maybe thats the issue...
Would be glad if I could resolve it anyway :D

Comment: Oh wait. The pods does not exist because they are completed

Comment: yes they are. Isnt that normal behavior? How can I change that?

Comment: I think this is it https://github.com/kubeflow/tf-operator/issues/128

Comment: Thank you! Does this mean, that I have to keep the pod alive somehow? E.g.  through adding a sleep at the end of the containers lifecycle? Seems pretty dirty to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is an upstream issue with kubeflow pipelines on microk8s, which is not working well together: https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/2347

I switched to Minikube, on which Kubeflow pipelines is running fine.